# Accessing / modifying submatrix of sparse scipy matrix

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

Suppose I have some Scipy sparse csr matrix, `A`, and a set of indices, `inds=[i_1,...,i_n]`. I can access the submatrix given by the rows and columns given in `inds` via `A[inds,:][:,inds]`. But I cannot figure out how to modify them. All of the following fail (i.e. do not change the matrix values):

- `A[inds,:][:,inds] *= 5.0`
- `(A[inds,:][:,inds]).multiply(5.0)`
- `A[inds,:][:,inds] = 5.0`

Is there any easy way to modify a submatrix of a sparse matrix?

Comment: Why are you using the `[][]` style of indexing?  Why not just one indexing bracket set?

Comment: Because `A[inds,inds] != A[inds,:][:,inds]`. This is just how I learned how to access an entire submatrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules for accessing a block, or submatrix, in `sparse` are the same [edit: similar] as for `numpy`.  The 2 index arrays need to be broadcastable.  The simplest way is to make the 1st one a column vector.

I'll illustrate:

```
In [13]: A = np.arange(24).reshape(4,6)

In [14]: M=sparse.csr_matrix(A)

In [15]: A[[[1],[2]],[1,2,3]]
Out[15]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [13, 14, 15]])

In [16]: M[[[1],[2]],[1,2,3]].A
Out[16]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [13, 14, 15]], dtype=int32)

In [17]: idx1=np.array([1,2])[:,None]

In [18]: idx1
Out[18]: 
array([[1],
       [2]])

In [19]: idx2=np.array([1,2,3])

In [20]: M[idx1, idx2].A
Out[20]: 
array([[ 7,  8,  9],
       [13, 14, 15]], dtype=int32)

In [21]: M[idx1, idx2] *= 2

In [22]: M.A
Out[22]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6, 14, 16, 18, 10, 11],
       [12, 26, 28, 30, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]], dtype=int32)
```

`M[inds,:][:,inds]` has the same problem in sparse as in numpy.  With a list `inds`, `M[inds,:]` is a copy of the original, not a `view`.  I've show that with reference to the data buffers in numpy.  I'm not quite sure how to demonstate it with sparse.

Roughly, `A[...][...] = ...` translates to `A.__getitem__(...).__setitem__(...,...)`.  If `A.__getitem__(...)` is a copy, then modifying it won't modify `A` itself.

Actually sparse matrices don't have distinction between views and copies.  Most, if not all, indexing produces a copy.  `M[:2,:]` is a copy, even though `A[:2,:]` is a view.

I should also add that changing the values of a sparse matrix is something you should do with caution.  In place multiplications (`*=`) is ok.

In place addition is not supported:

```
In [31]: M[idx1, idx2] += 2
...
NotImplementedError:
```

Modification of values may produce an EfficiencyWarning - if it turns a `0` value to nonzero:

```
In [33]: M[:2, :2] = 3
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py:690: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  SparseEfficiencyWarning)
```

---

The `np.ix_` answer to your previous question works here as well.
[Python - list of same columns / rows from matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33306386/python-list-of-same-columns-rows-from-matrix)

```
M[np.ix_([1,2],[1,2,3])].A
```

Comment: Thank you, interesting subtleties. I'm used to C++ where any reference, pointer or copy is explicit from a coding perspective. I'm using python for some prototyping, which is mostly great, but I need to figure this kind of stuff out a bit better.